# Java : Interface in a class is not accessible while importing

Tags: java, apache-spark, import, hive, classloader

[image]

I am using the maven dependency **hive-hcatalog-core** in my program

and this jar present in the project maven dependencies, with the interface (as in the image-top).

### The interface ICacheableMetaStoreClient , though present the class, is NOT  resolvable from import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common. (image -bottom)

consequently, while doing a spark-submit,  I am getting the exception :

> com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: 
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface 
>   org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$ICacheableMetaStoreClient
>   is  not visible from class loader

**What do I need to do for this to be visible from the program class path.**

Comment: Do you know if the internal class has a visibility of `public`?  If it doesn't, that'd explain why it's not visible.

Comment: The internal class is NOT public, unlike other classes. In that case is there any way to access this class

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at the code:

```
class HiveClientCache {..}
```

The `HiveClientCache` has only package level visibility and it along with `ICacheableMetaStoreClientwont` wont be available for import outside of that package (this includes in your code).

Now lets look at `ICacheableMetaStoreClient`:

```
@InterfaceAudience.Private
public interface ICacheableMetaStoreClient extends IMetaStoreClient {....}
```

The interface is public but has annotation on it that makes the Hive/Hadoop additional preprocessing to check object type and throw IllegalArgumentException.

Here is the JavaDoc for `InterfaceAudience`:

> Annotation to inform users of a package, class or method's intended
>   audience. Currently the audience can be InterfaceAudience.Public,
>   InterfaceAudience.LimitedPrivate or InterfaceAudience.Private. All
>   public classes must have InterfaceAudience annotation.
>
> - Public classes that are not marked with this annotation must be considered by default as InterfaceAudience.Private.
> - **External applications must only use classes that are marked InterfaceAudience.Public. Avoid using non public classes as these
>     classes could be removed or change in incompatible ways.**
> - Hadoop projects must only use classes that are marked InterfaceAudience.LimitedPrivate or InterfaceAudience.Public
> - Methods may have a different annotation that it is more restrictive compared to the audience classification of the class. Example: A class
>     might be InterfaceAudience.Public, but a method may be
>     InterfaceAudience.LimitedPrivate